# Getting user data to save from form 1 to form 2

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program that prompts the user to enter information on form 1 (firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, occupation, gender). When the submit button is clicked, the information fills a datagridview on form 2. I can get the program to fill the first row of the data grid, but I cannot get it to allow another entry from the user to be saved. I have been at this for some time now, any help would be appreciated. I will include my button click methods and my form 1 and 2 screenshots (I wont be able to provide screen shots till I get a higher rep) if that will help.

**submitButton**

```
private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (this.firstNameTxtBox.Text == "")
  {
    MessageBox.Show("First Name is a required field: Please enter your First Name");
    this.firstNameTxtBox.Focus();
    return;
  }

  if (this.lastNameTxtBox.Text == "")
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Last Name is a required field: Please enter your Last Name");
    this.lastNameTxtBox.Focus();
    return;
  }

  if (this.occupationComboBox.Text == "--Select an occupation--")
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Occupation is a required field: Please select your occupation");
    this.occupationComboBox.Focus();
    return;
  }

  if (!maleRadioButton.Checked && !femaleRadioButton.Checked)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Gender is a required field: Please select a Gender");
    this.maleRadioButton.Focus();
    return;
  }

  Data_Summary form2 = new Data_Summary();
  form2.Show();
  form2.summaryText.Rows.Add(firstNameTxtBox.Text, lastNameTxtBox.Text, phoneNumberTxtBox.Text, occupationComboBox.Text);

  if (maleRadioButton.Checked)
  {
    form2.summaryText.Rows[0].Cells[4].Value = "Male";
  }

  if (femaleRadioButton.Checked)
  {
    form2.summaryText.Rows[0].Cells[4].Value = "Female";
  }
}
```

**addAnotherButton**

```
private void addAnotherButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  summaryText.Rows.Add();
}
```

Comment: are you familiar with Properties, and or how to use public or protected variables..

Comment: You're making a new form2 every time you click on submit. I think you need to make a new form2 once and then try to add your rows to that form.

Comment: also make sure that the new form has some way of accepting the values that you are trying to assign upon creating and before showing

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot get it to allow another entry from the user to be saved" ? What is "saving" - is that filling the information on the other data grid? Do you get any errors?

Comment: I can get it to display the values in the first row, but like MahanGM said I am making a new form every time.  Everytime the addAnotherButton is clicked I want the user data to fill a new row.

Comment: Thank you MahanGM, and all. I got it to work now!